# Trying to install laravel passport

Tags: php, laravel-10

**Cant install laravel passport on laravel 10.**

I trying to install laravel passport but i have problem like this. I dont get it if this must downgrade my php version. Can anyone solve this?
Sry if my english is bad.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQ1CI.png

Comment: end of the composer install try with `-W` and see